# Caliburn Micro IoC/DI FactoryMethod

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, caliburn.micro

In Castle Windsor when I wanna use Factory method I simple create container like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISomeClass>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => { return new SomeClass(); } ));
```

How can I achive this same think with caliburn.micro integrated IoC container? I have read the documentation, but I still can not figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the `SimpleContainer` methods are simply convenience methods that use `RegisterHandler`. You can see this comment in [the docs](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container):

> Note: All of the above registration methods actually use Handles under the covers.

Or simply read [the source](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/SimpleContainer.cs). This method allows you to pass a function that takes a container and returns an object instance (`Func<SimpleContainer, object>`).

So you can just use `RegisterHandler` or the generic `Handler` extension method to register your factory:

```
container.Handler<ISomeClass>(container => new SomeClass());
```

Or:

```
container.RegisterHandler(typeof(ISomeClass), null, container => new SomeClass());
```